Azure Synapse Connection test successful in SQL Server ODBC Data Source Test, but errors in R
I successfully created a User DSN in ODBC Data Source Administrator with Azure Managed Service Identity authentication with ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server, for Azure Synapse. The connection test is successful, but when I use RStudio with the odbc package, I get the following error:

Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 08001: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Format file could not be opened. Invalid name specified or access denied.  [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Failed to authenticate the user 'BI_Dev_AML_ID' in Active Directory (Authentication option is 'ActiveDirectoryMSI').
Error code 0x9D43; state 40259
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Timeout error [258].   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired  [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Unable to complete login process due to delay in login response

Can someone help me find out what's going on?
Other connections (that don't require Managed Service Identity authentication) work just fine.
Thank you for any insight.
I tried checking and unchecking 'Trust Server Certificate' and tried to set Connection Encryption as Optional, Mandatory and Strict.
Even after the connection test is successful, if I go back to 'Change the default database to' section, the dropdown freezes, and throws the following message:

Connection failed:
SQLState: '28000' SQL Server Error: 18456
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for
user ''.


Before any RStudio settings, please attempt code in R with odbc package. Post full code block and error message.

The ERROR:

Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 08001: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Format file could not be opened. Invalid name specified or access denied. [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Failed to authenticate the user 'BI_Dev_AML_ID' in Active Directory (Authentication option is 'ActiveDirectoryMSI'). Error code 0x9D43; state 40259 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Timeout error [258]. [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Unable to complete login process due to delay in login response

Regarding the you need to use DBI-compliant interface to ODBC drivers. so that It would be easy to connect databases such as SQL Server.
I have tried the below approach:
You can install the latest release of odbc from CRAN with the below code:
install.packages("odbc")

Results:
Installing package into ‘/nfs4/R/user-lib/application_1728891227670_0003’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/odbc_1.5.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 299106 bytes (292 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 292 KB

Loading required package: usethis
* installing *source* package ‘odbc’ ...
** package ‘odbc’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
Found odbc_config cflags and libs!

Next, To use the odbc package, start by establishing a connection to the database, which could look like this:
library(DBI)
db_conn <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
  Driver = "SQL Server",
  Server = "SomeDBcls.xx.yy.zz.com",
  Database = "NameOfSchema",
  UID = "USER ID",
  PWD = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Database password"),
  Trusted_Connection = "Yes",
  Port = 1433,
  applicationIntent = "readonly"
)

Note: first you need to add TrustServerCertificate=yes; to your connection string.
Reference: r-dbi/odbc
